# Meaning of the numbers I just entered during a Maven Installation

Tags: maven

So just opend a Maven book, following directions to start with installing maven and when I said mvn archetype:generate ... during installation it started asking questions that I should enter values for the things it was asking! Well I know I will learn them later but mostly wanted to make sure the values I entered at this step won't screw up something else later:

```
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: 1
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: 1
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: 1
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: 1
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /Users/JonyIve
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /Users/JonyIve/1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: You have to define a correct groupId. Things like com.company and an artifactId like projectName and version like 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide proper values for these coordinates. Read more about them at http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-more-coordinates

Examples would be

- groupId: com.mycompany
- artifactId:  test-project
- version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

The rest .. just use the defaults.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What do you mean by "*You should not provide proper values for these coordinates.*"?